# startActivityForResult no funciona

Tags: android-studio, activity

tengo el siguiente problema en Android,

Tengo una activity A que lanza una Actividad B, desde la actividad B quiero agregar un contacto mediante:

```
    Intent contactIntent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
    contactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

    contactIntent
            .putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "Alguien")
            .putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "541234657");

    startActivityForResult(contactIntent, 2);
```

Eso lanza el gestor de contactos pero, cuando agrego el contacto y salgo, no vuelve a la activity B que fue quien lanzó el gestor de contactos, vuelve a la Actividad A directamente.

Gracias desde ya.

Comment: Por que no agregas el código completo de  actividad B?

Comment: José, dale una lecturilla a la **[documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html?hl=es-419)** (está en castellano). Dice claramente que la activity que recibe el resultado debe hacerlo a través del método `onActivityResult`, ¿lo estás haciendo así? No veo ese método en tu código.